# How to check a plain password to a hashed password at login in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have hashed password (using set_password) in my database table , I want to compare the hashed-password with my plain password using check_password to login successfully.

views.py/login view

```py
def logauth(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            messages.error(request, 'if part : user is not  None')
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('emp')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'else part : user is None')
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please provide valid credentials')
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

backends.py

```py
class MyBackEnd(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        existing_user = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
        if not existing_user:
            # Checking the user Regauth Custom DB.
            user_data = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
            if email == user_data.email:
                user = RegAuth.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return existing_user

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return RegAuth.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return False
```

Comment: You already do this: the `authenticate(..)` function will hash the raw password, and see if the two hashes are identical.

Comment: means with only (user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
will work??

Comment: @JayeshSakare: if the `user` is `None`, then the authentication failed, if it is a user, then that was the user. You can then decide to call `login` to log in the user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem except they have defined a custom auth backend which doesn't actually check the password but does some other bizarre things.

Comment: thats why posted question , (authenticate) it is not working..                               
giving error - RegAuth matching query does not exist. Regauth is my custome model

Comment: @DanielRoseman: yes, indeed. It is not clear to me at all why the OP wants to create a new authentication backend. Especially since it is not using some third party authentication service, so there is no "added value" in defining a new one.